# Parent fixed width (%), Two children autoadjust to parents width

Tags: html, css

I have been trying so many different solutions to solve this problem without reaching any solution that actually works so I cant post any css (since its not working properly, so I dont even know if its the correct "way" to build further on anyway).

**Case**: One div with width 100% (its parent varies in size) with two children inside. The div should never exceed hight of one text line/ text row.

```
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child">Text from left</div>
 <div class="child">Text from right</div>
</div>
```

**Goal**: Make the children divs auto adjust to fit as much text as possible (on that one row) and if the childrens width together exceed its parent div width then hide the overflowing text in second child with ellipsis.

Is this possible with pure CSS? With script I sort it but not with only CSS.

Thanks (sorry for bad english).